# VBA Workbooks.Open type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a really hard time opening a workbook in VBA.

This line of code gives me a type mismatch. `path` is a `String` and I am 100% sure it is valid and I am able to do the `.SaveAs` with `path` without issues.

```
' Compile Error: Invalid qualifier on Workbooks
Set wbNew = Workbooks(path).Open
```

I have tried other permutations like this one, but I get `Compile Error: Invalid qualifier` on the `Workbooks` object itself. Am I missing a reference?

```
' Compile Error: Invalid qualifier on Workbooks
Workbooks.Open path
```

How do I open a workbook in VBA?

Comment: Isn't the runtime error *subscript out of range* in the first snippet?

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the `Application.` part isn't a part of any SO question I could find, trust me, I spent a while looking at the one you linked and it wasn't obvious at all.

Comment: Would you happen to have some variable or function named `Workbooks` in scope? The name clashing would explain it.

Comment: @rlb.usa - From within Excel, `Application.Workbooks` *is* `Workbooks`.  You're just using the implicit global copy of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Set wbNew = Workbooks(path).Open
> ```

The `path` should be an argument to the `Open` method; you're passing it as an *index* to the `Application.Workbooks` collection - that's the collection of *workbooks already opened*, so `path` presumably wouldn't correspond to any already-opened workbook, hence the error.

So the correct and fully qualified call would be:

```
Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Set wbNew = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)
```

Comment: `Application.Workbooks.Open(path)` omfg, I spent hours googling and couldn't find that.

Answer (score -3):

TRY THIS

Path = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test.xlsx"

Dim myShell As Object

Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

myShell.Run Path

Comment: Why don't _you_ try it and verify that it works? After all, answers are only supposed to be written if you 100% know that it's correct. I think you'll be surprised by the result...

Comment: Sorry, i didnt paste everything. Ill double check next time.

Comment: No problem. StackOverflow gets easier the more you do it. Soon you'll be full time ;)

Comment: It worked it just needs to change the path... I hope :S is my first post. It worked for me.